# Mixing cmyk colours

Tags: color, cmyk, color-theory

I have a cmyk colour of 0,40,50,0

[image]

I want to change the magenta value, the 40%, to redder colour 0,67,70,28

[image]

And see what the resulting CMYK colour is. How I can go about doing this?

Comment: Well.. you can't ever print more than 100% of a color.

Comment: So... are you saying that you want to substitute the Magenta ink for a specific red colour?

Comment: Your answer would be 0,67,70,28. Unless you are picking a red from a RGB color space and converting to CMYK you already know your answer.

Unless you are trying to ask something else?

Comment: I believe you are saying you want to print like this (0(C), 40(0,67,70,28), 50(Y), 0(K)) What color this creates I do not know.

Comment: can you [edit] your question and rephrase it to be more clear?

Answer (score 2):

A) You can't create a CMYk color where *any* value is above 100%. There's no feasible way to mix your CMYk starting point with another CMYK color in terms of press ink. 100% is the maximum allowable value for any CMYK color.

B) For press, there may be a couple ways to handle this. i.e. You run a second pass.. print the first pass as 0/0/50/0 then *overprint* a second pass of 0/67/70/28. However, this is going to considerably *darken* all colors not just magenta areas. The magenta areas would end up being your brown/red but that extra yellow and black overprint is going to darken all other areas.

So really.... what color you are trying to achieve is kind of mystery....

[image]

As you can see that 50% yellow is going to alter everything even if you remove magenta and overprint your color.

If you *really* want to merely replace Magenta with your brown/red.. you *could* run a 5 color job (CMYK+1) leaving the Magenta plate empty. Areas where Magenta was *not* empty are going to create a deeper red....

[image]

<sub>(Pantone 471 is merely the color I felt was closest to 0/67/70/28, you might pick a different spot. I didn't spend a great deal of time looking and there is no *immediately* matching spot color I saw.)</sub>

Ultimately, it *may be* possible. However, much more detail as to *why* you need this, what your process is, and your end goal would assist in a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your response. It is a specific printing requirement (for traffic signs) where instead of magenta ink the company used red ink (BS381C No. 537 which is cmyk 0,67,70,28) - but they can't tell us the actual resulting cmyk colour.  What I am trying to know is what John Burgess said above i.e. what this colour is: (0(C), 40(0,67,70,28), 50(Y), 0(K))

Comment: It may just be the 0/67/70/28 then a second pass of 50% Y. Or it may mean all art is 50% or 67M70Y28K.. So it's just that some specific areas are pure 50Y while other areas are the 0/67/70/28 breakout.